# Set border color in listbox with binding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

I have a project in which I have in my main window a listbox of columns and inside of it I have a listbox of tasks for each column.
I need to change the border color of each task on some condition : i.e if 75% of the time has passed since we created the task it will be colored orange , red if overdue and so on.
how can i change a specific task in my listbox with binding ? 
I don't understand how to get the task details because it needs to happen instantly and not only if the task is selected.
any ideas ?

Comment: Bind the border brush. Use a converter to return the right solidcolorbrush depending on whatever your logic is.

Answer (score 1):

Use a ValueConverter.  While I don't know exactly what you mean by "75% of time has passed since we created the task", I will assume you mean as a deadline approaches.

Example:

```
    public class DueTimeColorConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            var dueTime = (DateTime)value;
            if (dueTime.Date >= DateTime.Now)
                return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
            else if (TimeSpan.FromTicks(DateTime.Now.Ticks - dueTime.Date.Ticks).TotalDays <= 2)
                return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Orange);
            return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

Then use it in your XAML by applying the value converter to your binding of the border color, based on the task's due date:

```
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
            <ListBox.Resources>
                <local:DueTimeColorConverter x:Key="colorConverter"/>
            </ListBox.Resources>
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Border BorderThickness="1">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Margin="5"/>
                        <Border.Style>
                            <Style TargetType="Border">
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{Binding DueTime, Converter={StaticResource colorConverter}}"/>
                            </Style>
                        </Border.Style>
                    </Border>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

My simplified "Item" class and its ObservableCollection:

```
            this.Items.Add(new Item() { Name = "Item 1", DueTime = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-7) });
            this.Items.Add(new Item() { Name = "Item 2", DueTime = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-6) });
            this.Items.Add(new Item() { Name = "Item 3", DueTime = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-5) });
            this.Items.Add(new Item() { Name = "Item 4", DueTime = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-4) });
            this.Items.Add(new Item() { Name = "Item 5", DueTime = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-3) });
            this.Items.Add(new Item() { Name = "Item 6", DueTime = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-2) });
            this.Items.Add(new Item() { Name = "Item 7", DueTime = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1) });
            this.Items.Add(new Item() { Name = "Item 8", DueTime = DateTime.Today });
            this.Items.Add(new Item() { Name = "Item 9", DueTime = DateTime.Today.AddDays(1) });
            this.Items.Add(new Item() { Name = "Item 10", DueTime = DateTime.Today.AddDays(2) });
            this.Items.Add(new Item() { Name = "Item 11", DueTime = DateTime.Today.AddDays(3) });
```

Example output:

[image]